# Pass and verify data between different razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

i'm using Asp.net Core2.1 Razor pages technology.

i want to ask about passing and verifying parameters between razor pages.
please not that i'm asking about the concept not about coding:

now suppose i have blogs, and each blog owned by a user who can manage it.

the user enter the manage page using this url :

```
https://localhost:44368/blogs/1/settings
```

as you see, the id of the blog is in the url:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
        // here i check that the blog is exist by the id
        // and i check if the current user own the blog            
}
```

then in the settings page i have links for several pages, for example (articles)
and the user can manage these articles.

```
https://localhost:44368/blogs/1/settings/articles
```

as you see still i have the blog id in the url :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    // now this function in the articles page
    // again i check if the blog is exist
    // and again i check if the current user can manage the blog or not                             
}
```

is this correct and good practice ? to check and verify in each page

or should i check only when i enter the settings page ?

or should i think in an approach to check only once when the user enter the settings page, then the user can't enter other pages based on the first check !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to keep web endpoints [*stateless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Statelessness).

So your approach of passing the Id to every child action, and validating this input, is correct.

To implement the other approach where you only check the Id once, you would need to pass state between the actions, e.g. as session state. This approach is less flexible. Maybe you want to be able to open the settings from another page than the blog details someday in the future?

Also remember that just because the user does not see a certain link on a page, nothing prevents her from entering e.g. `https://localhost:44368/blogs/1/settings/articles` directly into the address bar of the browser. So you will need some from of validation for every action in any case.